# Conditional update query to pad alphanumeric values in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have an Access table with a field that contains alphanumeric values (1234, 123A, 12A34, ABC3, etc). I am trying to create a conditional update query to add leading zeros to bring all values that contain at least 1 letter up to five characters but none to the only numeric values (eg 123, 00A12, 0000X).

My current code looks like:
`UPDATE MyTable SET MyTable!Field = Format(Field, String(5, "0")) WHERE MyTable!Field LIKE '*[A-Z]*'`

When I run the query, I don't get any error messages but it also fails to add any leading zeros.

I've also tried `Format(Field, "00000")` using `Not Like` and `'*[0-9]*'` or `'*[0123456789]*'` etc.

Interestingly, when I run a query by itself to select any of the values containing a letter (`Like '*[A-Z]*'`), it correctly pulls all 1000 values that need to be updated but when I add the conditional, it fails. Similarly, I've been successful in the past with adding leading zeros the entire field using `Format(Field), String(5, "0")` but it also fails when I add a conditional.

I'm pretty new to Access and SQL, so I feel like I've probably misunderstood the syntax somewhere. Or is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: `Format(Field), String(5, "0")` is not valid construction. It cannot prefix leading zeros. Must be an error in how you typed this expression in post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format() is wrong function to use.

If every value in field is 5 characters or less, consider:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Field = String(5-Len(Field), "0")) & Field WHERE Not IsNumeric(Nz(Field,0))
```

Comment: That does work, however, it adds zeros to all of my values and I was trying to add them to just the alphanumerics (so leave 123 as 123 but update 123A to 00123A).

Comment: Sorry, that does actually work. I'd miss-typed my field name when I first tried. Thank you!